# OAuth2 and PKCE - Code verifier is invalid

Tags: java, oauth, pkce

I'm making a Java App where I'm trying to implement an OAuth2-authorization flow for an API (Etsy.com) that requires PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange). I've been trying for some time now but I keep being stuck at the following error when exchanging the access code for the OAuth token:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"code_verifier is invalid"}
```

Here's the method for generating the initial URL where the sha256-encoded verifier is passed:

```
@Override
public String getOAuth2AuthorizationUrl() {

    String sha256hex = null;
    try {
        if(_currentVerifier == null)
            _currentVerifier = PkceUtil.generateCodeVerifier();

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(
                _currentVerifier.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        sha256hex = new String(encodedhash);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    UnicodeEscaper basicEscaper = new PercentEscaper("-", false);
    System.out.println("sha256="+sha256hex);
    System.out.println("veri="+_currentVerifier);

    String oAuth2AuthorizationUrl = super.getOAuth2AuthorizationUrl();
    var authUrl = oAuth2AuthorizationUrl
            +"&state=asdf&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge='"
            + basicEscaper.escape(sha256hex)+"'";
    return authUrl;
}
```

Then I'm sending the request to exchange the code for the token as application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST-request:

```
    UnicodeEscaper basicEscaper = new PercentEscaper("-", false);
 var params = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id="
            +token.getOwner().clientId+"&redirect_uri="
            +basicEscaper.escape("https://localhost")
            +"&code="+accessCode+"&code_verifier="+basicEscaper.escape(_currentVerifier)+"";
```

I tried many variations, also tried wrapping the values in '' etc. but nothing worked. Have I misunderstood this process? I'm sending a sha256 string initially and when requesting the OAuth2-token I'm sending the value that was encoded.
Any ideas?

Update:
I tried using Googles library for generating the hash, but I'm still getting the same error.

```
Hasher hasher = Hashing.sha256().newHasher();
    hasher.putString(CODE_VERIFIER, Charsets.UTF_8);
    HashCode sha256 = hasher.hash();

    System.out.println("veri="+AppUtils.encodeBase64(AppUtils.toHexString(sha256.asBytes())));

    String oAuth2AuthorizationUrl = super.getOAuth2AuthorizationUrl();

    var authUrl = oAuth2AuthorizationUrl
            +"&state=asdf&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge="+AppUtils.encodeBase64(AppUtils.toHexString(sha256.asBytes()));
    return authUrl;
```

Also the format of the code_challenge parameter looks different in the samples.

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge generation is incorrect. The hash of the verifier has to be [base64 url encoded](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5).

The standard says

```
code_challenge = BASE64URL-ENCODE(SHA256(ASCII(code_verifier)))
```

So this is wrong:

```java
sha256hex = new String(encodedhash);
```

It should be:

```java
sha256hex = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(encodedhash);
```

Also, *do not* put quotes around the challenge in the URL.

Side note: It is not necessary to escape the challenge and verifier because they are encoded in a url safe way

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. I've added some code in my initial post.

Comment: Add some example output (url and form body with challenge and verifier).

Comment: Just noticed this in your second attempt: `AppUtils.toHexString(...`. This is wrong. don't do it. Where is `AppUtils` from?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is pretty old, but I hope it saves somebody like me.
`code_verifier is invalid` is actually different from `PKCE verification failed` (the one keycloak gives me for using wrong verifier).

The standarts say that your key should be at least 43 characters long and not more than 128 characters max. You should also encrypt already basecoded version. This code worked for me:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();
        String inp = encoder.encodeToString(Utils.generateString(43).getBytes());
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        String res = encoder.encodeToString(digest.digest(inp.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Challenge: " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(res) + "\nVerifier: " + inp);
    }
}



public class Utils {
    public static Random random = new Random();
    public static String[] characters;

    static {
        String charS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        charS+=charS.toUpperCase() + "01234567890";
        characters = charS.split("");
    }


    public static String generateString(int length) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for(int now = 0; now<length; now++) {
            result.append(characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```